# Customizing command window prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, prompt

I am running a bunch of commands in a command prompt on a Windows server over a period of time and I would like to see when I last ran a command.  I used the `prompt` command to customize the prompt.

> prompt $t $p$g

to get a prompt that looks like

> 13:02:50.64 L:\>

I would like to use 12 hour time in the prompt and drop off the tenths/hundredths of a second, but it doesnt appear there is an option to do this.  I would like for it to look like

> 1:02:50PM L:\>

Perhaps someone knows a way?

---

Using

> prompt $T$H$H$H $p$g

gets me a prompt that looks like

> 15:35:11 L:\>

Which is closer, but it doesnt look like it will do 12 hour format.

Comment: Not really an answer for `cmd.exe` but in `PowerShell` you can do `function prompt {"$(get-date -format h:mm:sstt) $(get-location)> "}`. A pity `cmd.exe` is not as powerful :( (maybe you can run the commands in a powershell :)

Comment: I can, however cmd is old habit that is hard to break

Answer (score 1):

For the PROMPT command, from [this page](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?prompt.htm), it says to use `$T` for 12-hour time. This DOES still have the tenths/hundredths of a second, but I don't think this can be removed.

Comment: Maybe you can use `$H` to remove the fraction?

Comment: `prompt $T $p$g` does **not** give a 12 hour format in `cmd.exe`. The linked site is only for the "Take Command" (TCC) environment (a non-free replacement for `cmd.exe`). **Not** for the normal `cmd.exe` command prompt.

Comment: The $H worked (prompt $T$H$H$H $p$g) Which is an improvement.  but there as @Rik said, the other command is for another shell

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The information below is wrong. The system locale settings will affect the time format returned by TIME /T at the command prompt, but apparently the $T in the prompt string is always in 24-hour format.

The $T variable in the prompt string is linked to the "Long Time" format setting in Windows. If your Windows settings specify a 24-hour time clock, that will be reflected by $T. To get 12-hour time, you need to change the Windows locale settings (which may not be desirable, because it will be system wide).